# Why is this function call ambiguous though conversion to bool requires an additional step?

Tags: c++, pointers, type-conversion, function-pointers, implicit-conversion

Consider the following code:

```
struct Foo
{
    typedef bool (*fptr_t)(int);

    operator fptr_t() const
    {
        return _func;
    }

    fptr_t _func;
};

class Wrapper
{
public:
    Wrapper(const Foo&) {}
};


void foo(bool b)
{
}

void foo(Wrapper w)
{
}

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    foo(f);
}
```

Which doesn't compile with an "ambiguous call to overloaded function" error.
As I see it, both `foo` overloads would require a user-defined conversion. However for the `Wrapper` version, the conversion goes

`Foo->(user-defined conversion)Wrapper = exact match`

while for the `bool` version the conversion goes

`Foo->(user-defined conversion)fptr_t->(implicit conversion)bool = exact match`

which requires an additional step. Furthermore, cppreference states (although I couldn't find the exact paragraph of the standard)

> If two conversion sequences are indistinguishable because they have
> the same rank, the following additional rules apply: 1) Conversion
> that does not involve pointer to bool or pointer-to-member to bool is
> better than the one that does.

which also seems to be the case here. So why is this call still ambiguous?

Comment: just a simplified version of the same issue, if it can help: https://godbolt.org/z/hWT54PY3q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both conversion sequences are user-defined conversion sequences.

User-defined conversion sequences that contain different constructors/conversion functions are always considered ambiguous, no matter whether additional standard conversion sequences in the user-defined conversion sequence differ in rank.

Comment: Right, so the key part is "User-defined conversion sequence U1 is a better conversion sequence than another user-defined conversion sequence U2 **if they contain the same user-defined conversion function or constructor or they initialize the same class in an aggregate initialization** and <...>", which is not the case here. That's what I was missing, thank you.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall Yes, correct, and there is no other bullet in the list that can distinguish two user-defined conversion sequences.